# ¿Como puedo validar desde jquery un formulario que se repite varias veces dentro de un ciclo while?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

Estoy intentando validar un formulario que cuenta con inputs (tipo radio) que se repiten a través de un ciclo `while` mientras  se encuentren datos en la db.

No logro como validar estos formularios dinámicos mediante jQuery ya que si lo dejo que valide solamente los input que estén chequeados; cuando elija cualquier input ya cumpliría con la condición, pero necesito validar varios input que se encuentran dentro de un formulario distinto.

**¿Cómo podría validar que cuando no este seleccionado alguna opcion de alguno de los formularios me diga que faltan opciones por seleccionar?**

Acá esta el código:.

#### PHP

```
$contacform = 0;

while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($resultados)) {

    echo '<div class="con">';
        echo '<p id="p">'.$contacform.'</p>';
    echo '</div>';

    echo '<form id="myformid" data-form="'.$contacform.'"align="center">
        <h2><strong>'.utf8_encode($row['pregunta']).'</strong></h2>
        <br>
        <label>'.$row['opcion1'].'</label>
        <input type="radio" name="check" id="check" value="1" required />
        <input type="hidden" name="checkd" value="'.$row['id_pregunta'].'" checked/>
        <br>
        <label>'.$row['opcion2'].'</label>
        <input type="radio" name="check" id="check" value="2" required />
        <br>
        <label>'.$row['opcion3'].'</label>
        <input type="radio" name="check" id="check" value="3" required />
        <br>
        <label>'.$row['opcion4'].'</label>
        <input type="radio" name="check" id="check" value="4" required />
        <br>
    </form>';

    $contacform += 1; 
}

echo '<div class="text-center">';
echo '<br>';
echo '<button class="btn btn-primary text-center enviartest">Enviar</button>';
echo '</div>';
```

#### JavaScript

```
$('.enviartest').click(function(){
    var selected = [];
    var selectedid = [];
    var my = [];

    /* Recorro el contador que se encuentra  en la etiqueta p dentro del div  con class con */
    $('.con p').each(function(){
        // alert($(this).attr('id'));

        /* obtengo lo que tiene  el  texto  de la  etiqueta p */
        var o = $(this).text();

        my.push($(this).attr('data-form'));;

        var definit = $('#myformid'+o+'input[name=check]');

        /*intento validar que cuando  seleccione   el formulario  numero  tal   y este  chequeado  el input con name  check  que es array me  mande un mensaje*/
        if ($('#myformid '+o+'input[name=check]:checked').is(':checked')) {
            alert('hola soy un cero');
        }else{
            alert('elije algo');
            alert(o);
        }

    });

    /*los input  que tengan  name  check y esten  chequeados  checked*/
    $('input[name=check]:checked').each(function(){
        selected.push($(this).val());
    }); 

    /*los input  que tengan  name  check y esten  chequeados  checked*/
    $('input[name=checkd]').each(function(){
        selectedid.push($(this).val());
    });

});
```

Comment: Hola @Jacks, bienvenido a [StackOverflow en Español](http://es.stackoverflow.com). Por favor sé más explícito con tu duda, especifica qué quieres decir con **validar** y qué parametros son requeridos para un formulario sea válido.

Comment: Recomendación: crea IDs únicos. El código que pones genera duplicidad de IDs lo que te puede traer problemas más adelante.

Comment: @AlvaroMontoro colocando "form[]" los podría recorrer y recociendo los hijos que tiene ese form puede validar si hay campos vacíos. Que recorra todos (con un for) y coloque un boolean que cambie el estado del mismo cuando haga falta un campo. Si quiere obtener cual campo en especifico es un poco mas complicado el proceso.

Comment: @PabloContreras no dije que quitar los IDs solucionara el problema. Dije que era una recomendación porque podría traerle problemas más adelante. Tener IDs duplicados es mala práctica y mal código.

Comment: @AlvaroMontoro bueno, no me explique bien. No estoy contradiciendo el comentario tuyo, solo estoy sugiriendo algo y te etiquete a ti a ver si parece buena practica? así lo hago yo en mi sistema para validar los form dinámicos.

Comment: @PabloContreras deberías ponerlo como respuesta. Lo menos que conseguirías sería un +1 por mi parte

Answer (score 1):

**Codigo PHP** mandas la variable `$contactform` al id del formulario para distinguirlo: `myformid0`, `myformid1`, `myformid2`... `myformidn`

```
$contacform = 0;

while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($resultados)) {

echo '<div class="con">';
    echo '<p id="p">'.$contacform.'</p>';
echo '</div>';

echo '<form id="myformid'.$contacform.'" data-form="'.$contacform.'"align="center">
    <h2><strong>'.utf8_encode($row['pregunta']).'</strong></h2>
    <br>
    <label>'.$row['opcion1'].'</label>
    <input type="radio" name="check" id="check" value="1" required />
    <input type="hidden" name="checkd" value="'.$row['id_pregunta'].'" checked/>
    <br>
    <label>'.$row['opcion2'].'</label>
    <input type="radio" name="check" id="check" value="2" required />
    <br>
    <label>'.$row['opcion3'].'</label>
    <input type="radio" name="check" id="check" value="3" required />
    <br>
    <label>'.$row['opcion4'].'</label>
    <input type="radio" name="check" id="check" value="4" required />
    <br>
</form>';

$contacform++; 
}

echo '<div class="text-center">';
echo '<br>';
echo '<button class="btn btn-primary text-center 
enviartest">Enviar</button>';
echo '</div>';
```

**Codigo JS**

```
$('.enviartest').click(function(){
var selected = [];
var selectedid = [];
var my = [];

/* Recorro el contador que se encuentra  en la etiqueta p dentro del div  con class con */
$('.con p').each(function(index, value){
    // alert($(this).attr('id'));

    var o = $(this).text();

    my.push($(this).attr('data-form'));;
    //colocas el index al id del form
    var definit = $('#myformid'+index+' '+o+'input[name=check]');


    if ($('#myformid '+index+' '+o+'input[name=check]:checked').is(':checked')) {
        alert('hola soy un cero');
    }else{
        alert('elije algo');
        alert(o);
    }

});

/*los input  que tengan  name  check y esten  chequeados  checked*/
$('input[name=check]:checked').each(function(){
    selected.push($(this).val());
}); 

/*los input  que tengan  name  check y esten  chequeados  checked*/
$('input[name=checkd]').each(function(){
    selectedid.push($(this).val());
});

});
```

Answer (score 0):

Necesitas agregarle un numero de identificación al formulario, en cada ciclo que generes uno nuevo, de esta manera los podrás accesar a través de jQuery haciendo referencia por su id, getElementByID('form1'),  getElementByID('form2'),  getElementByID('form3')

Cuando generes el formulario, guarda el numero de formularios que generaste, y así podrás obtener en jquery el n-esimo formulario.

Saludos

Comment: A ver @sibok666  no entiendo mucho     yo hago eso desde el php  es decir  hago un contador y le  asigno un numero dependiendo de  cada form tal cual ahora en java script  haría algo como esto ?   '                                      var elec =[];  
                                                 
$('.con p').each(function(){
                elec.push($(this).text());;
       });'                                                                                                  `for (var i = 0;  elec.length < 0 ;  i++) {
       alert(elec[i]);
 } `    ?